# How to remove mounted locations that have been added using the mount command?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I've mounted few shared locations using the below command.

```
mount -t cifs /mnt/systemfolder -o username=name,password=password //10.10.1.1/My-Shared-Folder
```

A few incorrect locations* have been erroneously mounted while running this command. Now when I execute just the `mount` command, it lists all the right and wrong locations I've mounted.

- - I have mounted the same location multiple times.

How do I remove locations that show up from executing the `mount` command so that I can remove the incorrect ones I've mounted?

The `umount` command does not help me remove the mounted location. Here's a screenshot showing the results to the `mount` and `umount` commands.

[image]

Comment: For future reference, I had the same error: This utility only unmounts cifs filesystems. when trying to unmount a CIFS mount whose parent directory had been moved (effectively moving the mountpoint). This error would occur when trying to use `umount` on either the correct mount point (where the mount was moved from) and when trying to remove the mount via the source mountpoint name (`//ip/path`). To successfully unmount, I ran `umount` on the new location of the mountpoint on the loca

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have several directories that are mounted over other directories (the second mount on `/mnt/arcserver` shadows the first one and so on, and the mounts on `/mnt` shadow the prior mounts on `/mnt/arcserver`). This is confusing both for humans and to the `umount` command. Unmount them from the bottom up:

```
umount //10.49.4.20/Released
umount //10.49.4.20/released
umount //10.49.4.20/released
umount //metro/released
umount //metro/released
umount //metro/released
```

If even that fails because `umount` is tripping on the multiple identical mounts, in desperation, unmount all cifs mounts:

```
umount -a -t cifs
```

On Linux, you can unconfuse the situation by moving mounts so that each has its unique, non-overlapping mount point.

```
mkdir /TMPMNT/{Released,released{1,2},arcserver{1,2,3,4}}
mount --move //10.49.4.20/Released /TMPMNT/Released
mount --move //10.49.4.20/released /TMPMNT/released1
mount --move //10.49.4.20/released /TMPMNT/released2
mount --move //metro/released /TMPMNT/arcserver1
mount --move //metro/released /TMPMNT/arcserver2
mount --move //metro/released /TMPMNT/arcserver3
mount --move //metro/released /TMPMNT/arcserver4
```

After this you'll have separate directories for each mounted filesystem, which you can explore and unmount at your leasure.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the mount order. Thanks for the multiple suggestions too! I had to first `umount` /mnt and then /mnt/arcserver worked.

Answer (score 7):

maybe with `umount -f` ?

> -f     Force unmount (in case of an unreachable NFS system).  (Requires kernel 2.1.116 or later.)

Or maybe you can do it with `umount -l`

> -l     Lazy unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem  hierar- chy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon
>   as it is not busy anymore.  (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or later.)

from: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

but looking around I found something [here](http://muzso.hu/2008/05/15/error-with-umount.cifs-this-utility-only-unmounts-cifs-filesystems).

```
$ umount.cifs /folder
```

**UPDATE**
Check the manual of umount.cifs... maybe it could give you an extra hand:

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/umount.cifs.8.html

> umount.cifs unmounts a Linux CIFS filesystem. It can be invoked
>   indirectly by the umount(8) command when umount.cifs is in /sbin
>   directory, unless you specify the "-i" option to umount. Specifying -i
>   to umount avoids execution of umount helpers such as umount.cifs. The
>   umount.cifs command only works in Linux, and the kernel must support
>   the cifs filesystem. The CIFS protocol is the successor to the SMB
>   protocol and is supported by most Windows servers and many other
>   commercial servers and Network Attached Storage appliances as well as
>   by the popular Open Source server Samba.

Comment: Tried all three suggestions. They all give the same repetitive messages. That last one only gives the message only once.

Comment: @Tomas I found something about the umount.cifs take a look at it.

Comment: `umount -i` did the trick. All other suggestions here did not work for me. RHEL 4

Comment: `umount -l` saved my day

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the mount point, try unmounting the device

```
 umount //metro/released
```

Answer (score 1):

try `umount`.

```
umount /mnt/systemfolder
```

Comment: Tried it and it didn't help. I get the message `This utility only unmounts cifs filesystems`. I did mount the locations using cifs. Unsure why this message then.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? According to the manpage, umount will call `/sbin/umount.<suffix> {dir|device} [-nlfvr] [-t type.subtype]`. So it should call `umount.cifs` which should do the trick for you. Did you try mounting something else there? Maybe you should try calling `umount.cifs` directly? Or looking up its manpage directly (`man umount.cifs`)?

Comment: I've added some additional information to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, looks like you're picking up an unusual `umount`.  Can you try running `/bin/umount` explicitly?

Comment: Just tried that, same results.

Answer (score 1):

For fstab record (ubuntu 14.04):

```
10.10.70.18:/nfs01      /backup                 nfs     rw,hard,intr    0 0
```

I was able to unmount this dead share using:

```
umount -l -i '10.10.70.18:/nfs01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the solutions here didn't work for me. I had this output from mount:

```
//10.0.0.173/e$ on /mnt/mount_tmp type cifs (rw,mand)
```

I tried the `mount --move` and the `umount -a -t cifs` alternatives, didn't work. I tried unmounting both `//10.0.0.173/e$` and `/mnt/mount_tmp`, nothing worked for me. I also tried the `-f` and `-l` proposed, to no success. Then I found this solution:

https://serverfault.com/questions/310015/cannot-unmount-cifs-mount

It tells you to use `-i`. It didn't work when I tried in the mounted folder:

```
$ umount -f -i /tmp/mount_tmp
umount2: Invalid argument
umount: /tmp/mount_tmp: not mounted
```

but it finally worked, when using in the "device":

```
$ umount -i '//10.0.0.173/e$'
umount: //10.0.0.173/e$: not found
```

Even though it reported an error, a subsequent run of "mount" shows that it's no longer mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact same problem, but couldn't get any of the above to work. Every time I remounted the directory, it tried to connect to the missing server (as well as the existing one).

I had to FIRST umount the directory, THEN the broken device:

```
$ sudo umount /backup
$ sudo umount -l -i '//anonymized.to/protect/the/stupid'
$ sudo mount /backup
```

Answer (score -1):

Running

```
$ umount -i
```

fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Hi Mike and welcome to U&L. Could you add a little bit more details to your answer?